# For Loop to count up and then down like snake

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello I want to programm a FOR-loop that counts x up to 126 and set y to 42 and then count x downwards to 25 and set y to 44.

i currently use:

`for y in range (40,110,2): 
 for x in range(25,128,2):`

But this counts x to 126 and then starts at 25 again with y setting +2
I want to make it like a snake kinda thing
Sorry for the poor descirption.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: snake kinda thing? give us a proper example

Comment: I mean it should count X to 126 and then set y 42 after that count x backwards so it goes to 25 after then set y 44 and count upwards to 126 again and so on

Comment: Maybe it's easier to help if you provide a simpler example with the expected states.

Comment: I want to move a Plotter via a Programm in Python but i dont want the Plotter to move Upwards at its X Axis with Y being 40 and then move down and set Y to 42 and move up again to 126. It would be better if he could just set Y to 42 when he is already up X axis (at 126) and then move down directly because im using a break currently of 10 seconds so he has time enough to move down again. if i can make that it moves like a snake (serpentines) i would safe much more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it now like this:

```
x_has_changed = False
for y in range (40,110,2): 
    if x_has_changed == False:
        for x in range(25,128,2):
            x_has_changed = True
            print 'X{} Y{}'.format(x,y)
    else:
        for x in range(128,25,-2):
            x_has_changed = False
            print 'X{} Y{}'.format(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the loop is fine: `for y in range (40,110,2)`, the second part is trickier.

You need to find a way to determine when you are counting un and when down.

- This could be her using a flag and 2 different for loops and changing the flag after they finish thus having one loop counting up and one counting down inside an `if else` statement and swapping the flag value every time y changes.
- You could also try to find a mathematical operation on y that gives you True or False depending on its value, which will probably involve `(y/2)%2` being the first 2 due to the step on y and the second because you want to differenciate 2 states.
- Another solution would be to set an x_options list and revert it every time y swaps value with `x_options = reversed(x_options)` and the interate over the list as `for x in x_options:`